# How do I print a snscrape output

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter

I'm trying to print the output of scraping a twitter feed using snscrape.  It works on command line but I can't get it to print to file.
My code:

```py
import snscrape.modules.twitter as twitter
maxTweets = 10
keyword='salvation'
for i, tweet in enumerate(twitter.TwitterSearchScraper(keyword + ' since:2021-11-01 until:2023-01-01 lang:"en" ').get_items()):
    tweets = {
             "tweet.url" : tweet.url
            }   
    print(tweets)
```

It prints to the command line but when I try:

```py
with open('file.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    print(tweets, file=f)
```

then it won't print and I get an error message:

`future warning username is deprecated, use user.username instead`

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** printing after you `open` the file with `mode='w'` [in write-mode] means the file will be over-written with every print and only the last print will show up. If you want all the `tweets` objects preserved, you should be appending instead, **inside** the loop [because if you print outside the loop, again only the last will be saved as `tweets` is also over-written every loop]:

```py
# for i, tweet in...
    # tweets = ....
    with open('file.txt', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        print(tweets, file=f)
```

---

This doesn't make any sense - that's a *warning* message, not an error message, and it shouldn't halt or break your program; and also, that warning shouldn't appear **unless you have something like `tweet.username` somewhere in you code** [and if you do, then you should probably replace it with `tweet.user.username` as the warning instructs].

I am unable to reproduce the error, and how you print shouldn't really have anything to do with triggering the message, but if that's really the **only** difference between when the message appears and when it doesn't, then you can try some other method to save it to the file, like collecting all the tweets into a list [in the loop] and then [after the loops] converting that list to multi-line string to write to the file:

```py
import snscrape.modules.twitter as twitter
maxTweets = 10
keyword='salvation'
timeStr = 'since:2021-11-01 until:2023-01-01 lang:"en" '
twGen = twitter.TwitterSearchScraper(f'{keyword} {timeStr} ').get_items() 

allTweets = []
for i, tweet in enumerate(twGen):
    if i > maxTweets: break

    tweets = {
             "tweet.url" : tweet.url
            }   
    allTweets.append(tweets)

## [OUTSIDE loop]
with open('file.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write('\n'.join[str(t) for t in allTweets])
```